# Is it possible deploy single SSIS package to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Can I deploy a single SSIS package to SQL Server 2014 from Visual Studio 2017? When I right-click on the package and select Deploy Package, I get an error "Package deployment mode is not supported on server with version lower than SQL Server 2016." I would like to avoid deploying the entire project (.ispac).

Comment: What's the problem to deploy all project? You should change you're project name to unique like 'test_project' and deploy you're solution.
In 2014 i don't know any solution better than this. The procedure of deleting project from SQL Server is simplier than deleting a package

Comment: I have over 100 SSIS packages in one project. I was hoping to deploy a single package rather than the project.